# ST_Intersects returns true while ST_Contains returns false for a point located outside of polygon

Tags: postgis

I am seeing some inconsistent results with the below query. We are testing if a point intersects a multipolygon. ST_Contains returns false as expected but ST_Intersects returns true incorrectly. The point is way outside of the the search area as shown in the map below. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Full Query - https://pastebin.com/raw/qq0qGwgg

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(box, point) intersects, ST_Contains(box, point) contains
    FROM (
     SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-89.963802,43.09416],
      [...coordinates truncated for brevity...]
      [-89.549422,43.081271]]]]}'), 10) As box,
     ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-89.7766 43.5287)'), 20) As point) As foo;
```

[image: Map showing point and the search area]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the actual geometries that result from your buffer construction? Intersects = true can happen if the edges of each polygon touch, and such a case would correctly return false for st_contains.

Answer (score 3):

Your data is in lat-long and no projection is set. The `st_buffer` applies a radius of "unknown" units, which are in this case degrees.

The buffer around the point is 20 while the buffer around the polygon is 10, so if the point is less than 20 degrees away from the polygon, their buffer will intersect each others.

If you swap the geometries in ST_Contains, it will print that the box (polygons) is within the point (buffer)

```
SELECT ST_Contains(box, point) contains,  ST_Contains(point, box) boxInPoint
    FROM ...
```

To fix it, you would need to either set and use a projection whose unit is in meters (or ft or else, but not degrees), or cast to geography.

Let's note that it is more accurate to check for proximity/intersection using `st_dwithin` than with a buffer.

Comment: I'd just like to add some more emphasis on `ST_DWithin` <-- **use it!** It is faster, more versatile and the recommended method for proximity search.